# multiple cursor shown in Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

i am facing a weird problem. In my EditText:

1) I can see multiple cursor when user type anything.

2) Hint is also visible even when user is typing something. 
Kindly refer to the screenshot

[image]

Following is layout XML:

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         >

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/actvCountry"
            style="@style/autoCompleteTextTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
            android:hint="@string/select_country_hint"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
            android:textSize="26sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etMobileNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvCode"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvCode"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvCode"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="12"
            android:paddingLeft="80dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
            android:textSize="26sp" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/tvCode"
            style="@style/editTextTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/actvCountry"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textSize="26sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMsg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etMobileNumber"
            android:layout_below="@id/etMobileNumber"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:text="@string/enter_country_code_mobile"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnProceed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvMsg"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_button_selector"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="26sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Following is the background set in EditText (edittext_background.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="@color/white" />
<padding
    android:bottom="5dip"
    android:left="5dip"
    android:right="10dip"
    android:top="5dip" />
```

Any suggestion are welcome.

Comment: can you upload the more xml code ?

Comment: uploaded complete XML

Comment: I see your code is fine...try cleaning and rebuild project..

Comment: unfortunately already tried cleaning and rebuilding   :-(

Comment: your code is working fine on my machine. try cleaning it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why problem was coming, but it got resolved after modifying my edittext_background. I have added transparent background. New XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="@color/white" />
 <solid android:color="#00000000" />
<padding
    android:bottom="5dip"
    android:left="5dip"
    android:right="10dip"
    android:top="5dip" />
```

Comment: I really hate hate hate hate hate hate hate hate hate HATE HATE HATE HATE HAAAATTTTEEEEE android so much...... thanks so much Sulabh....!