# Android 7.0 EditText two cursor

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here is EditText Code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_contact_search_text_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="31.0"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/contacts_search_edittext_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_search"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5.0"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_tab_search_contact"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I was in Android7.0 following the phone test, no problem. But I use Android7.0 phone test, EditText will appear two cursors. As shown below:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471637/multiple-cursor-shown-in-edittext

Answer (score 1):

Add "paddingLeft" attribute to edittetxt,it can be a work around but helped me
`android:paddingLeft="2dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Setting EditText's height to `wrap_content` or `40dp` works