# How to fix Android UI flickering bug?

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin

I have a problem with the Android UI bug. I provided one example picture of the bug.

Example:

1. When I type quickly in the input field, I get multiple selectors in the
   text field.
2. If I double click on the text in the editText field (text selector appears), and if I move it, I get the state that is shown in the picture below.
3. When focusing on some of the fields, the background flickers and for half of the second, the background loses its color.
4. Some random flickering when focusing on some input fields

I recently added pictures functionality in my app, but I cannot resolve at what point this error occurred.

[image: after moving selector image]

Comment: Do you have a custom background for your View?

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv yes, I have rounded_background.xml where the topleft and topright corners are slightly rounded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple cursor shown in Edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471637/multiple-cursor-shown-in-edittext)

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv Unfortunately it's not the issue, I had it before and I got the problem some time after it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had hardware acceleration disabled in the manifest file.